# Class not inheriting all methods/variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, inheritance, subclass

I have two classes, one is a parent and one a child.  For some reason, when I inherit from the parent, not all methods/variables are available.  Specifically, trying to access `__bar` on `Child` returns an error but on `Parent` it functions as intended.  Really not sure what is going on here. Here is a simplified example:

test.py:

```py
class Parent:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__bar = 1

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print(self.__bar)

Child()
```

Expected output is just `1`, but the error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 10, in <module>
    Child()
  File "test.py", line 8, in __init__
    print(self.__bar)
AttributeError: 'Child' object has no attribute '_Child__bar'
```

Although `.__bar` is defined in `Parent` and I called `super().__init__()` to initialize it.

Comment: You need to make a [mre]. This is too much code, you haven't shown how you're calling the classes, and you need to add the traceback for the error messages.

Comment: Should be fixed to meet your criteria now.

Comment: That was fast! Kudos for being responsive! I see the problem now, you've gotten into name mangling accidentally. This might be a duplicate, but if not  I'll post an answer once the question is reopened.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  After you saying it was name mangling, I started messing around with it.  I didn't realize that my child class wouldn't be able to call methods with two underscores (__) from the parent class.  I went back and changed all __ methods to _ and it works!

Comment: I was able to get a [mre] down to 10 lines of code, so do you mind if I replace your example?

Comment: Here's my MRE: https://gist.github.com/wjandrea/bccd6b8fc68e1a9b502c98c2661cbc34

Comment: Sure, that's definitely easier to read.  Thank you.

Comment: Python interpreter renames fields with name starting from `__`. For ex, `dir(Parent())` shows `'_Parent__bar'` instead of `__bar`. that's why you have error in `Child` - python tries to access `_Child__bar` field that doesn't exist